# JS object -> JSON submission from jquery ajax -> php iteration

Tags: php, javascript, json, object, casting

I'm building a process where js object gets submitted to a php file via ajax (POST and json type) and I'm having problem iterating through what's been submitted in php.

My object looks like this:

```
var myObject = {
  "section1":{
  "subitem1":"value1",
  "subitem2":"value2"
 },
  "section2":{
  "subitem3":"value3",
  "subitem4":"value4"
 }
}
```

My ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
url:"test.php?section=section2",
type:"POST",
dataType:"json",
success:function(data){
// what i do with the response data
},
data:myObject
});
```

Here's my php:

```
$section = $_GET['section'];
$json = json_decode($_POST[$section], true);

foreach($json as $key=>$value){
   //if this iteration works here, it'll be the happiest point of my day
}
```

Now, in the php above, if i refer to the certain section as $_POST['section2'], then iteration does work. So using PHP's variables variable seems to be the issue but i don't know....Whole $_POST also seems to come in as an object. DOES JQUERY AJAX automatically do JSON.stringify on the object that i'm submitting? I've tried using stringify but it didnt work.. i have latest version of chrome...

Also, I tried using json_decode on the $_POST too... still $_POST[$section] gets interpreted as null...

Any help, suggestion, advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you var_dump the $_POST array so we can see how it's recieving the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to what you think, stringify the object and send it as part of a key/value pair and then decode it from the post field.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test.php?section=section2",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
    // what i do with the response data
    },
    data:{json:JSON.stringify(myObject)}
});
```

```
$section = $_GET['section'];
$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);
$current_section = $json->{$section};

foreach($current_section as $key=>$value){
   //if this iteration works here, it'll be the happiest point of my day
}
```

Comment: thanks! I haven't tested this yet but here's question i have:
if converting the object into json when submitting it to the php is the case, shouldn't i use `JSON.stringify(myObject)` instead of `$.parseJSON(myObject)` ? Doesn't `$.parseJSON(myObject)` used to create object out of json?

Comment: Another side question i have is what is the standart/best practice way of iterating through what's been submitted via ajax?
Whether to treat the incoming variable (POST or GET) as multidimensional array or object? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @StillQuestioning you're right, I fixed it. Data coming in $_GET or $_POST  are always strings or arrays of strings(if the name has a `[]` at the end it will be part of an array), the developer should know what to expect, if they don't them something wrong. Read more http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: I've followed your instruction and made sure and confirmed php receives json in string and successfully used `json_decode()` to get an object or an associative array. However, I'm still having an issue with using variable to refer to a specific child object/array dynamically. Essentially, `$current_section = $json->{$section};` isn't working for me. Weird thing is if i manually do `$current_section = $json->{"section2"};` IT DOES WORK... BUT MY APPLICATION HAS TO REFER TO THIS ELEMENT DYNAMICALLY... any ideas?? help.. thanks..

Comment: @StillQuestioning the second parameter of `json_decode` was wrong and returned and array, I removed it so it returns an object. I tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: thanks for walking me through this.. ahh.. it does work for me if i specify string like "section1" instead of $section... i even tried $_GET['section'] instead too... my php runs in a function..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $_POST array only has one value--the object--try this:

```
$section = $_GET['section'];
$tmpArray = json_decode(array_pop($_POST), true);
$json = $tmpArray[$section];
```